# How Do I Install Another Distro Over Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, partitioning, mount, disk, iso

I am pretty new at this, and I understand this is a pretty novice question but I am wanting to erase Ubuntu on my laptop (not enough RAM or hard-drive) and install a smaller distro over Ubuntu.

I have the ISO and it is actually mounted.  It appeared as if I was getting pretty close.  I thought I would need to run the file inside the "install" folder (pretty logical right? ... Especially since it's the only file there...) but nothing happens when I click it.

Any ideas?  I appreciate it.

Comment: Normally you install distros by booting their install CD. However, this question is not Ubuntu related.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is:

1. Remove Ubuntu, by erasing the partitions that Ubuntu uses
2. Boot with the distro CD and install

I don't know what distro are you planning on installing, but Ubuntu has lighter variations.

You can simply download one of them, boot form the CD and install over your current Ubuntu instalation

Some variations:

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) - Ubuntu with Lxde

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) - Ubuntu with XFCE

[Fluxubuntu](http://fluxbuntu.org/) - Ubuntu with Fluxbox

More variations [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/list-of-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-and-live-cds.html)

There's also a [Ubuntu Light](http://www.ubuntulite.org/)  it could do the trick for you, but the official site is down.

I suggest you download a minimal instalation of Ubuntu and build your system from the ground, install only what you need.

If you're not confortable with this, try Xubuntu or LUbuntu

Comment: Thanks for your help man!  It was greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote or accept the answer as valid, so other users can use it too.